# Thunderbird freezes for a minute or so every time it starts

Tags: thunderbird

I am running Thunderbird 102.3.3 on Ubuntu 22.04.

When I start up Thunderbird the window that appears can't be moved at all for a minute or two. Every few seconds a warning appears asking if I want to kill the window or wait. If I click wait repeatedly eventually it starts up OK.

I can see that it is trying to load 70,000+ flags and it is during the loading of the first 10,000 that the freeze occurs.  The same thing happens if I quit thunderbird and then start it up again.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Here’s [a filtered search in Thunderbird’s issue tracker for the word `freeze`](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?query_format=advanced&short_desc=freeze&order=Importance&resolution=---&product=Thunderbird&classification=Client%20Software&classification=Developer%20Infrastructure&classification=Components&classification=Server%20Software&classification=Other&short_desc_type=allwordssubstr). You may want to have a look at it, then file an issue for your experience if it’s not already covered.

Comment: Have you considered reducing the number of messages, reminders and other items that slow startup? One way *might* be to move them to archive or local folders to see if that helps. Also, move the T-Bird proflle to SSD, rather than HDD.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Flatpak version instead of the Ubuntu default repo version by applying the following steps:-

1. Open the terminal by pressing `Ctrl + Alt + T`.
2. Uninstall Thunderbird from the Ubuntu default repo by entering the following command then press `enter`:

```
sudo apt remove thunderbird --purge --auto-remove -y
```

3. Install Thunderbird from Flatpak by entering the following command then press `Enter`:

```
flatpak install org.mozilla.thunderbird -y --noninteractive
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely reduce the number of messages in Inbox.

Also, a frequent cause of startup slowness is calendars with many repeating appointments.